# Posting Advertisements on Chol Hamoed

Tags: halacha, chol-hamoed, business

What do the sources say about posting flyers on Chol Hamoed, advertising one's shop (as open generally, not as open only on Chol Hamoed), or is that considered business on Chol Hamoed?

Comment: He should ask a rabbi. We don't know all the relevant details (nor are we a rabbi).

Comment: @DoubleAA I thought I was pretty clear!

Comment: Isn't this a request for p'sak? @DoubleAA

Comment: Edited so that the question does not request a psak.

Answer (score 2):

See [heWikipedia](http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%97%D7%95%D7%9C_%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%A2%D7%93) which records the types of permitted work on  Chol Hamoed:

> צרכי אוכל נפש:  preparation of food for the moed days.
>
> שאר צורכי המועד:  other things needed for the moed.
>
> מלאכת דבר האבד: work where a loss (not, I learnt, a lack of profit)
>   would be incurred by not doing it.
>
> מלאכה לצורך מצווה: work needed to perform a mitzvah.
>
> צרכי רבים: work for the public good
>
> פועל שאין לו מה לאכול: work for a worker who cannot sustain himself.

At [Kipa.co.il](http://www.kipa.co.il/ask/show/194912-%D7%A2%D7%91%D7%95%D7%93%D7%94-%D7%91%D7%9E%D7%97%D7%A9%D7%91-%D7%91%D7%97%D7%95%D7%9C-%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%A2%D7%93) 
הרב דוד לוי writes that

> פרסום אסור בחול המועד אלא אם מדובר באירוע שיהיה בחול המועד, פורסם לפני
>   כן וזקוק כעת לפרסום חוזר
>
> Advertising is prohibited on Chol Hamoed unless it is for an event
>   occurring on  Chol Hamoed which had been previously advertised and now
>   needs repeating.

These conditions do not apply to the discussed case.